# Ignore revision on git-svn fetch?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I am trying to move one of my Subversion repositories to Git and am running into an interesting error... In the middle of the git-svn fetch step, I receive the following error:

```
r9 = d0eff6b2d1eda7fcced16227dbc613732e956f0b (refs/remotes/git-svn)
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/baytn/baytn/trunk': PROPFI
ND of '/baytn/baytn/trunk': 500 Internal Server Error (https://1three.svn.codeba
sehq.com) at C:\Program Files\Git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5047
```

When I go look at the revision history for the SVN repository I see that Revision #9 was an empty commit, how this happened, I am not sure.

Is there any way for me to get around this error?

Best regards,
Andrew

Comment: hi @Andrew, did you find any work around for this? I need to do the same. Please post your findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your commits:

with git:

- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

with svn:

- undo commit: http://markphip.blogspot.com/2007/01/how-to-undo-commit-in-subversion.html
- Filter: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.reposadmin.maint.html

Comment: Will this work being my repository is on revision 238? I need to basically skip revision 9 when doing git-svn fetch so it can pull the repository down.

Answer (score 15):

If you do a `git svn fetch` to get all revisions and it fails on revision 9, you can just continue with:

```
git svn fetch -r 10:HEAD
```

If I know there is a revision that will be an issue, it can be skipped this way (assuming revision 9 is the problem):

```
git svn fetch -r 0:8
git svn fetch -r 10:HEAD
```

Comment: what will be the result in your next git commit in the history? will all the skipped commit be squashed to the next commit?

Comment: @Zennichimaro That is what appears to happen - the skipped commit is squashed into the next commit